# Detect device using Varnish

Tags: caching, theming, proxies

I have some difficulties finding a correct code (VCL) to configure varnish to detect if the device is a tablet or a mobile or a desktop.

Here is the best [module version](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/mobile_switch_varnish/tree/README.txt?id=b3eeddd9a90c86ef33b9e171d159e2b200098632) found today, but still not detecting tablet if not an iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very tricky but see this helpful link.

[Varnish device detection and redirect to mobile site](http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/varnish-device-detection-and-redirect-to-mobile-site/2011-11-29)